# Is it a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $X$. Then
 $\sup_{p\ge 1} d(x_n,x_{n+p}) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ implies  $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. 
Any hints or counterexample to prove or disprove this implication? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would just go straight to the definition.  Fix $\epsilon>0$ and try to use the hypothesis to show there is some $N$ such that $|x_m-x_n|<\epsilon$ for all $m,n\ge N$.  Notice what you are given shows there exists some $M$ such that $|x_n-x_{n+p}|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge M$, $p\ge 1$.  Is it now sufficient to take $N=M$?

Answer (score 3):

Given $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that $\sup_{p\ge 1}d(x_nx_{n+p})<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. Then for all $m>n>N$, we have $d(x_n,x_m)\le \sup_{p\ge 1}d(x_n,x_{n+p})<\epsilon$.